# regex for a list of separated values where values may contain the separator character

Tags: javascript, regex, separator

I'm trying to capture the patterns in a string having the following form : item(options),item(options), etc.
where "item" is a word, and options can contain any characters.
An item may have no options, so the string can be "item,item, item(options),item".

So far I've come with this:

```
/(\w+(\(.+\))*)(,(\w+(\(.+\))*))*/
```

But that does not really works. I want to be able to capture all the results, so that i can have an easy access to items and options. Any help would be appreciated !

**EDIT**:
I'm afraid it's not possible : if "options" can contain any characters, like "," or ")", then a proper regex cannot be written, can it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
/
    \w+                 : one or more word characters
    (?:                 : start non capture group
        \([^)]+\)       : an open parens, some characters that are not parens, a close parens
    )?                  : this group is optional
    (?:                 : start non capture group
        ,               : a comma
        \w+
        (?:
            \([^)]+\)
        )?
    )*                  : 0 or more times the same pattern preceeded by a comma.
/x                      : allow comments in regex
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great improvement to my first regex. The part excluding the closing parens does not seem to work for me anyhow. I tested on this and the match doesn't go the end : "item,item2(option1,option2,option(3)),item3,item4(options)"

Comment: @Cyrille: You have nested parenthesis, that's why it doesn't work, it's not a job for regex. I'm afraid you have to write a parser instead.

Comment: I think you're right, this is much more complicated than I thought at the beginning. Thanks.